# Is there an online floor planner that recommends layouts for a house for all rooms?

Tags: floor-plan

I found a few floor / room planners online already that recommends room layouts based on function (eg bathroom, kitchen etc.), but is there a planner where I give the basic house dimension, eg 20m * 10m and gives a complete room layout idea? Perhaps I could set the number of bathrooms / bedrooms, but the tool would plan the rest? :)